# Xcode 12 beta 4 - Unable to upload to TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm attempting to upload a beta of my app for iOS 14 to TestFlight distribution.

While Xcode trying to upload the ipa it show an error
"App Store Connect Operation Error - An error occurred uploading to the App Store."

How can I solve it ?

I also tried to use "Transporter" but I can't login in the app for this error "This action cannot be completed at this time (-22411)"

Thanks

Comment: I'm also having this error and I recently updated to Big Sur. Guess we wait stackoverflow.com/a/35663309/8793423